# Using xbasej with NTX indexes

Tags: java, indexing, vb6-migration, dbf, advantage-database-server

I am trying to use DBF files from Java for newer utilities that interact with a large older system. I am able to access, read, write, update using the Java ODBC bridge but this does not update the NTX indexes. I found xbasej which claims to be able to use indexes but seems only to be able to use NDX indexes. I could always create them before using them but then it will still not update the NTX ones used by all the other programs. There are several thousand programs interacting here so just switching to NDX is not possible and I have no budget.

So my question is: Is there any way to make xbasej use NTX indexes or failing that is there any other free Java library that can auto update the NTX files if I open them all before editing the database?

Oh and I have forwarded port 6262, and even tested with my firewall off totally.

Any help will be most appreciated.

I have found the Sybase Advantage drivers [link](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1055532) Which can apparently open DBF and NTX files, I can use their Data Architect program to create a data dictionary to access my data but I cannot work out how to use it from Java, all the examples seem to require some sort of server connection. Something like this should work:

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBFTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    try {
        ADSConnection conn = (ADSConnection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:extendedsystems:advantage://localhost:6262;catalog=//llama-rog/c/stock/DD.add;user=master;password=master");   
    }catch (SQLException ex) {        
        Logger.getLogger(DBFTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        
}
```

Every time I attempt to connect I get:

```
com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSException: [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage JDBC]Connection refused: connect
at com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.n.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)
at dbftest.DBFTest.main(DBFTest.java:30)
```

I have searched for hours and come up totally dry for any example code to connect to a local only data dictionary (.add) which has my DBF and associated indexes listed. Someone mentioned using the alias that the Data Architect creates in ADS.ini but again there is no trace of how to do this. The Jar file does not come with a javadoc, only some HTML help files which I have trawled through and found nothing.

There is a tester app which supposedly lets you test out connections but still requires me to type in my connection string, user name and password and neither through data dictionaries nor free tables am I able to connect to anything, I always get the same error.

Does anyone have any idea how to get this working. The fact that it works through their data architect tool proves that it should work somehow but exactly how I can copy that functionality, I don't know.

Comment: NTX indexes are from CA-Clipper, an old DOS programming language. While the .DBF files are standard dBase III, the index files are a proprietary format, so unless you can find an ODBC driver specifically for Clipper databases you're probably out of luck. (Most people switched to using FoxPro 2.x compatible .CDX index files in part for this reason. The other reasons were compound indexes (multiple indexes in a single file), compression, auto-open functionality, and plain speed.)

Comment: Yeah, you are quite right, the system was originally built using DBaseIV in clipper (hence the clipper indexes) still my boss insists on writing the occasional clipper program despite the 64bit incompatibility. I don't really need it to be an ODBC library, I am happy with how xbasej does it or anything else really, I just want to be able to update the indexes.whenever we write new programs we always have to re-index after every little change which with the size of some of our files takes a really long time.

Comment: Let me rephrase what I said to be what I meant. :-) "so unless you can find a **Java library** that supports Clipper databases". As I said, the .NTX format is very vendor-specific. Maybe some of the [info here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_%28programming_language%29) will help you locate something. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Advantage JDBC driver requires Advantage Database Server, which is the client-server version of the product.  Based on the comment "no budget", I'm guessing you haven't purchased the server.  If that is the case, then the JDBC driver will not be of any use to you.  It seems likely that the `Connection refused` error is occurring because there is no server to accept the connection.

If you are able to use an ODBC bridge, then one possibility it to use the Advantage ODBC driver, which can connect to Advantage Local Server (the non-client-server version, which is free based on your usage ... read the license).  You should be able to install the Advantage ODBC driver, set up a data source that specifies the data dictionary (using same path as you used with Advantage Data Architect).

You probably did this already, but when you created the data dictionary and added the tables, make sure you added the appropriate .ntx files for each table.  Advantage has no way of figuring which indexes would belong to which table otherwise.

Comment: I can use an ODBC bridge so I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, this worked fantastically. I created an ODBC connection to the Advantage data dictionary and added some records and they worked immediately without needing to reindex. This has been driving me crazy for months and the answer was so simple in the end.

Comment: As a note to any future readers, the JVM and ODBC must both use the same architecture I initially set up a 64 bit ODBC with a 32 bit JVM. You have to use c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe to configure a 32 bit version on 64 bit windows.

Comment: @feldoh:  Cool - thanks for reporting back on the results.  I'm glad you got it working.